# Track the Device Motion in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer, core-motion, panorama-control

> I want to track the device's movement along X-axis in a straight line
>   just like panorama.

I try with Accelerometer but can't able to track this.

I think it only detect the Device Rotation. I search a lot for the tutorial of Grayscope, Magnetometer, etc.

**Any one can give the sample of the Core motion?**

Help me to solve this.

Thank you.

My code is as follow:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    xval=0;
    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;
    NSOperationQueue *aQueue = [NSOperationQueue alloc];
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:aQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"X value is: %f", motion.userAcceleration.x);
        if (motion.userAcceleration.x > 0.05) {
            //a solid move forward starts
            //lineLength++; //increment a line length value
            xval=xval+10;
            ball.frame=CGRectMake(xval, 361, 119, 104);
        }
        if (motion.userAcceleration.x < -0.02 ) {
            [motionManager stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I think this post would help you, if not, let me know I might have another suggestion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176281/ios-detect-movement-of-user Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Thanks a lot again !!! Wait i am trying

Comment: It shows me the **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

Comment: Just see my code is Question.

Comment: Hmmm

This could be because

- The pointer used to point to memory that was ok, but its chunk was deallocated.
- The pointer is corrupt.

Comment: When I try to change the motion then it shows me a error because **motion is not a motion manager object & app is still crash.

Comment: The bad access error is kinda messy, I'd understand it more to get rid of this error, something like this article might help http://loufranco.com/blog/understanding-exc_bad_access

I hope I was if a help!
Let me know what happens please.

Comment: Sorry but i can't check the zombie in device & there no issue as far as memory concerned.

Comment: Are you trying to do this when a camera picture is taken and saved?

Comment: @iSeeker, yes you are right.