# I get OSSpinLockLock when calling startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue inside a controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

In my root controller I have a property with the `CMMotionManager`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CMMotionManager *MManager;
```

In its getter I do lazy instantiation. When the controller's view loads, I call this method

```
- (void)reloadAccelerometer {
    NSLog(@"Away we go");
    self.MManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 10.0/60.0;
    [self.MManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:self.queue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Y values is: %f", motion.userAcceleration.y);
    }];
}
```

I see "Away we go" in the `NSLog` and then immediately the app crashes and I get this thread log

```
libsystem_platform.dylib`spin_lock$VARIANT$mp:
0x39a87814:  movs   r1, #1

libsystem_platform.dylib`OSSpinLockLock$VARIANT$mp + 2:
0x39a87816:  ldrex  r2, [r0]
0x39a8781a:  cmp    r2, #0
0x39a8781c:  it     ne
0x39a8781e:  bne.w  0x39a893ec                ; _OSSpinLockLockSlow$shim
0x39a87822:  strex  r2, r1, [r0]
0x39a87826:  cmp    r2, #0
0x39a87828:  bne    0x39a87816                ; OSSpinLockLock$VARIANT$mp + 2
0x39a8782a:  dmb    ish
0x39a8782e:  bx     lr
```

What's my mistake? Did i place `reloadAccelerometer` in the wrong place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was trying to do something similar in my iOS app and spent *forever* trying to figure out what the cause of the crash was. This was a very cryptic (and pesky) exception. I eventually figured it out after reading through the crash reports that `OSSpinLock` has to do with **a thread / queue management issue**.

The `NSOperationQueue` is the culprit here. Your code doesn't show how you were creating your `NSOperationQueue`, but I assume it was something like this:

```
NSOperationQueue *aQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]; // Do NOT do this
[self.MManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:aQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Y values is: %f", motion.userAcceleration.y);
}];
```

It turns out that this is **not** the way to use the `NSOperationQueue`. That `aQueue` object is the cause of the crash.

To properly setup the operation queue and avoid a crash, you should move your CMMotionManager to a different thread. Then tell NSOperationQueue to use the **`currentQueue`**, NOT the `mainQueue`. Apple recommends that it is not run on the `mainQueue`, however if your app is currently running in the main queue then I don't see how the `currentQueue` is any different. I tried moving the code below to a different queue using GCD, but no code was ever called.

Here's what your final code should look like:

```
// Check if Motion / Location services are available
if (motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable == YES && motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == YES) {
    NSLog(@"Away we go");
    self.MManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 10.0/60.0;
    [self.MManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Y values is: %f", motion.userAcceleration.y);
     }];
} else {
    // Motion / Accelerometer services unavailable
}
```

I should also note that your creation of the `CMMotionManager` property (to my knowledge) is correct with `(strong, nonatomic)`.

Comment: Wow, brilliant answer! Thanks RazorSharp :)